How can I add clickable link in word comment
How can I add clickable link in word comment using office js Here is example image
Here is my format of comment:
export const formatComment = (comment: any) => {
    return `
        : ${comment.author} 
         : ${comment.bias_type} 
        : ${comment.severity} 
         : ${comment.original_text} 
        : ${comment.suggestion} 
        : ${comment.justification} 
         : ${comment.source_link} 
    `.replace(/\n\s+/g, '\n\n').trim();
};

